# Конкатенация строк на С++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Помогите с таким заданием: мы получаем две строки(символьных массива), и передаём их в функцию для конкатенации(это я сделал только как-то костыльно мне кажется), но нужно ещё сделать так что бы когда мы передаём в функцию число третьим параметром, строки объединялись до этого числа... например: str1 = Hello, str2 = World, length = 3, в итоге без указания длинны функция должна вывести Hello World, иначе Hello Wor, вот что сделал: (у меня в случае если длину то вместо объединения оно перезаписывает первую строку второй, хотя в прошлом приложении на С это вроде работало, может накосячил где..)
P.S. и наверное лучше это всё сделать с использованием указателей, но я вообще запутаюсь, пока не знаю как это нормально сделать :D

```
const int size_of_str = 100;

void fill_str(char str[]);

void str_conc(char str1[], char str2[], int length = 0);

int main()
{
    char str1[size_of_str];
    char str2[size_of_str];

    cout << "Input first str: ";
    fill_str(str1);
    cout << "input second str: ";
    fill_str(str2);

    cout << "Conc without length" << endl;
    str_conc(str1, str2);
    cout << "Conc with length" << endl;
    str_conc(str1, str2, 3);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void fill_str(char str[]) // заполнение массива.
{
    int inpt, i = 0;

    while (((inpt = getchar()) != '\n') && i < (size_of_str - 1))
    {
        str[i++] = inpt;
    }

    str[i] = 0;
}

void str_conc(char str1[], char str2[], int length)
{
    int i, j;

    if (length == 0)
    {
        cout << str1 << str2 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for(j = 0; str1[i] = str2[j]; i++, j++);
        cout << str1 << endl;
    }
}
```

UPD:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


const int size_of_str = 100;

void fill_str(char str[]);

void str_conc(char str1[], char str2[], int length = 0);

void str_conc(char *str1, char *str2, char *res, int len = 0);

int main()
{
    char str1[size_of_str];
    char str2[size_of_str];
    char result[size_of_str] = {0};

    cout << "Input first str: ";
    fill_str(str1);
    cout << "input second str: ";
    fill_str(str2);

    cout << "Conc without length" << endl;
    //str_conc(str1, str2);

    str_conc(str1, str2, result);
    cout << result << endl;

    cout << "Conc with length" << endl;
    //str_conc(str1, str2, 3);

    str_conc(str1, str2, result, 2);
    cout << result << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void fill_str(char str[]) // заполнение массива.
{
    int inpt, i = 0;

    while (((inpt = getchar()) != '\n') && i < (size_of_str - 1))
    {
        str[i++] = inpt;
    }

    str[i] = 0;
}
void str_conc(char *str1, char *str2, char *res, int len)
{
    int copy_len = (len == 0 ? strlen(str2) : len);

    strncpy(res, str1, strlen(str1));
    strncpy(res + strlen(str1), str2, copy_len);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вывод строк еще не является конкентацией строк. В стандартной библиотеке есть функции для  работы со строками. Для конкетации строк можно выполнить следующее:

```
void str_conc(char str1[], char str2[], int length)
{
    if (length == 0)
        strcat(str1, str2);
    else
        strncat(str1, str2, length);
}
```

После вызова функции, в строке `str1` будет нужная вам строка. И это далеко `не C++`, а чистый `С`. В C++ все намного легче:

```
std::string str1, str2;
std::cin >> str1 >> str2;
str1 += str2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
int main()
{
    char result[100]{0};
    str_conc("Hello", "World", result, 4);

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}

// str1, str2 без изменений
// res - строка, в которую будет записан результат
// res обязан быть по длине больше или равен, чем str1 + str2 + 1
void str_conc(char *str1, char *str2, char *res, int len)
{
    int copy_len = (len == 0 ? strlen(str2) : len);

    strncpy(res, str1, strlen(str1));
    strncpy(res + strlen(str1), str2, copy_len);
}
```

Comment: ну это работает, благодарю, меня правда смущает что у меня по факту конкатенации то и нет вообще XD то есть просто если нету третьего параметра - выводит оба массива, иначе первый и часть второго))
по хорошему же вроде надо что вторая строка с первой соединялось и всё это оставалось в первом массиве вроде)

Comment: В таком случае без указателей вам не обойтись никак, либо используйте std::string

Comment: не подскажите как это доработать с указателями? пока довольно плохо в них разбираюсь(
а про std::string вообще не знаю, только вот начал изучать пару дней назад после С, с которым трудности тоже имеются)

Comment: Про  динамическую память читали?

Comment: Обновил вам пример с использованием указателей

Comment: Спасибо, динамическое выделение изучал, но не идеально его помню и умею работать с ним, практиковался мало просто)

Comment: хм, в этом примере если вызвать str_conc(str1,str2,result,4) то о но выводит всё полностью, работает как нужно только если передавать захардкоженные строки как в примере

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, код

Comment: Добавил нынешний код в свой вопрос наверху.

Comment: Во первых, вы не зануляете result перед вторым вызовом, и в нем хранятся результаты предыдущей конкатенации. Добавьте memset((void*)result, 0, size_of_str); между вызовами str_conc. Во вторых, у вас при вводе строк остается "\n", что мешает корректному выводу. Добавьте это: str[i - 1] = 0; в конец функции fill_str